# Dynamically changing Mouse speed

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Guys, I have a C# Winforms application with a panel inside the form. What I want to do is, whenever the mouse pointer enters this panel, I want to slow the movement speed of the mouse by 50%. Once the pointer moves outside this panel, I want to speed of the mouse to resume normal 100% speed. How can I accomplish this in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://web.archive.org/web/20111119033345/http://www.sparrowtail.com/changing-mouse-pointer-speed-c?) article might help

Here's the code from the article:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MouseSpeedSwitcher
{
    class Program
    {
        public const UInt32 SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071;

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern Boolean SystemParametersInfo(
            UInt32 uiAction, 
            UInt32 uiParam, 
            UInt32 pvParam,
            UInt32 fWinIni);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SystemParametersInfo(
                SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 
                0, 
                uint.Parse(args[0]), 
                0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the article. For icemanind: just call the function specified in this article on the "Enter" and "Leave" events, slower when the control is entered and faster when leaving the control, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public const UInt32 SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 0x0070;


        const UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        const UInt32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern Boolean SystemParametersInfo(
            UInt32 uiAction,
            UInt32 uiParam,
            IntPtr pvParam,
            UInt32 fWinIni);

        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
           MouseOptions m = new MouseOptions();

            MouseOptions.GetDefaults();
            int speed;
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSESPEED, 0, new IntPtr(&speed), 0);
            Console.WriteLine(speed);

            MouseOptions.SetDefaults();


            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSESPEED, 0, new IntPtr(&speed), 0);
            Console.WriteLine(speed);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        public class MouseOptions
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int SystemParametersInfo( int uAction, int uParam, IntPtr lpvParam, int fuWinIni );

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern int GetLastError();

            public const int SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 112;
            public const int SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 113;


            private static int intDefaulSpeed = 10;
            private static int intCurrentSpeed;
            private static int intNewSpeed;

            public static void GetDefaults()
            {
                intCurrentSpeed = GetMouseSpeed();
            }
            public static void SetDefaults()
            {
                if ( intCurrentSpeed == 20 )
                {
                    SetMouseSpeed(intDefaulSpeed); 
                }
                else if ( intCurrentSpeed < 10 )
                {
                    SetMouseSpeed(intDefaulSpeed);   
                }
            }

            public static int GetMouseSpeed()
            {
                int intSpeed = 0;
                IntPtr ptr;
                ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSESPEED, 0, ptr, 0);
                intSpeed = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);

                return intSpeed;
            }

            public static void SetMouseSpeed( int intSpeed )
            {
                IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(intSpeed);

                int b = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0, ptr, 0);

                if (b == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not able to set speed");
                }
                else if ( b == 1 )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully done");
                }

            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Meghraj, I have the same requirement but I want to move the mouse cursor on a desktop slowly (I want to change speed). I am using SetCursorPos Win32 API to set move cursor to the required point. Can you explain more to achieve it ?

Comment: public static extern int SystemParametersInfo( int uAction, int uParam, IntPtr lpvParam, int fuWinIni )
Above  system function 
 Retrieves or sets the value of one of the system-wide parameters. 
 This function can also update the user profile while setting a parameter.
To access this function/method we need to import  DllImport("user32.dll")
uAction:- Here we pass constant of control's operation in my case I am passing  below constant
"SPI_SETMOUSESPEED" for setting/changing mouse cursor speed
"SPI_GETMOUSESPEED" for to get system's mouse cursor speed

Comment: uParam:-
 A parameter whose usage and format depends on the system parameter being queried or set. For more information about system-wide parameters, 
  see the uiAction parameter. If not otherwise indicated, you must specify zero for this parameter.
lpvParam-:
 A parameter whose usage and format depends on the system parameter being queried or set. For more information about system-wide parameters, 
 see the uiAction parameter. If not otherwise indicated, you must specify NULL for this parameter. For information on the PVOID datatype, see Windows Data Types

Comment: GetDefaults() -This method i used for getting system's current mouse cursor speed & storing in variable.
               If i want to restore old value i can use stored mouse cursor speed
SetMouseSpeed( int intSpeed ) -This method i used for setting system's mouse cursor speed.
SetDefaults() - This method I used to restore  system's mouse cursor speed.

Comment: @user1915370  , please read all details i had commented above.Still there is any doubt you have please free to ask

Answer (score 0):

As it was not very clear how to use code from the answers, I found more concise solution for changing Mouse speed. Add this code to class where you want to change the speed:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto),]
public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);
```

And then call SystemParametersInfo with required Mouse speed:

```
//SPEED is an integer value between 0 and 20. 10 is the default.
SystemParametersInfo(113,0,SPEED,0);
```

Not forget to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` [Credits.](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?426873-Change-Mouse-Speed)