# Programmatically move mouse cursor with adjustable 'speed' of cursor movement

Tags: c#

I got the code to move the mouse cursor from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c) question.

My project involves using face tracking to move the mouse cursor, but the face cannot move too much. How do I adjust the sensitivity of the movement, as in the face need only to move a little for the mouse cursor to move a lot, like adjusting the mouse sensitivity in the windows settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically changing Mouse speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931122/dynamically-changing-mouse-speed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The measurement from your face tracker would create a measurement **value** from the range [**low1**, **high1**]

Your `Cursor.Position.X` would take a value between zero to screen width. Lets notate this range as [**low2**, **high2**].

You need to assign `Cursor.Position.X` such as:

`low2 + (value - low1) * (high2 - low2) / (high1 - low1)`

The range you define as [**low2**, **high2**] will determine the speed of the movement. Shorter range will move the mouse faster.

Comment: I assumed that tracker value is linear

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on it a little bit more? I don't really understand it. The `moveCursor()` method that I use accepts the center of the face as a `Point`. Do I replace value with `point.X` ?

Comment: That example is about clipping rectangle. You need to do `Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);` in order to change cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a factor to adjust the transformation from face movement to cursor movement.