# Configuring Windows (10) mouse key settings with commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, configuration, command

So hi,

I'd like to be able to change my Windows mouse key settings on the fly.
To achieve this I was thinking some commands ran with a batch file (or anything else, doesn't have to be a batch file obviously) would be something that's possible(?).
I could easily program a batch file to be ran by the press of a button with my keyboard.

Does anyone know if/how I could configure my mouse key settings without actually opening the ease of access center and going there? 
The thing I'd mainly be changing would be:
[image]

Any replies are highly appreciated, and remember, it doesn't have to be exactly what I said, I just want a way to achieve this. 
I'm open to any options, thanks.

Comment: check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931122/dynamically-changing-mouse-speed) and [**this**](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5260&start=15#p50787)

Comment: thanks @npocmaka I'll take a closer look at those when I can.
Also, I found this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373593(v=vs.85).aspx

I'd appreciate if someone who's smarter than me could take a look at that and tell if that's something I can use to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Make a text file which you can call swapmouse.cs, containing this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

class SwapMouse
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SwapMouseButton(Int32 bSwap);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int rightButtonIsAlreadyPrimary = SwapMouseButton(1);
        if (rightButtonIsAlreadyPrimary != 0)
        {
            SwapMouseButton(0);  // Make the left mousebutton primary
        }
    }
}
```

And compile it to swapmouse.exe with this command in a terminal window:

"`%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc" swapmouse.cs`

Just run the .exe file, if you want to get it back to it's original state, just run the .exe file again.