# C# programm change mouse sensitivity

Tags: c#, windows, performance, unity-game-engine, mouse

My goal is to create a little software to change dynamically the mouse speed of my mouse. I want to create a .dll of it and insert to my Unity Project to give the choice of my player to choose their mouse sensitivity.

On my research I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931122/dynamically-changing-mouse-speed/52364365#52364365) with the code below:

```
public const UInt32 SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071;

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern Boolean SystemParametersInfo(
        UInt32 uiAction,
        UInt32 uiParam,
        UInt32 pvParam,
        UInt32 fWinIni);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Arg[{0}] = [{1}]", i, args[i]);
        }

        SystemParametersInfo(
            SPI_SETMOUSESPEED,
            0,
            uint.Parse(args[0]),
            0);
    }
```

But, when I try to use this code in my Visual Studio I have this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'The index is outside the bounds of the array.'

I tried to use the breakpoint, but this is not working, and I don't understand what is going in my arg[0].

I'm new in pur C# and I would like to know if I have to create a windows or handle input in order to have my program working.

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: Are you passing in a value to set the mouse speed to as an argument when you run the program?

Comment: Depending on what your doing this can probably be accomplished within Unity - for example by polling for raw input then multiplying by a factor.  Currently your taking a sledge hammer and changing values for the entire system.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have added this code to a console application. The `string args[]` parameter passed into the `Main()` method is an array of parameters taken from the command line.

For example, in the following command line: `C:\> setmousespeed.exe 25`, `args` will contain a single string value of `"25"`. The line `uint.Parse(args[0])` converts the string into an integer.

To use this method in a Unity application, you should convert the code to a publicly accessible method. An example of this is shown below.

```
public static class Utility
{
    public const UInt32 SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071;

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern Boolean SystemParametersInfo(
        UInt32 uiAction,
        UInt32 uiParam,
        UInt32 pvParam,
        UInt32 fWinIni);

    public static void SetMouseSpeed(unit speed)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Arg[{0}] = [{1}]", i, args[i]);
        }

        SystemParametersInfo(
            SPI_SETMOUSESPEED,
            0,
            speed,
            0);
    }
}
```

Once imported into Unity, the above code can then be called as follows:

```
Utility.SetMouseSpeed(100);
```

To import into Unity you should also add this code to a Library (DLL) project, but I believe this is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Just got couple of question, you put a for loop for showing the arguments but there is no main. My goal is A) put a number for testing multiple  mouse sensitivity just for testing, or B) having a UI with a + ou - button in order to change my sensitivity.

Anyway i don't know what i'm suppose to do with my main function (especially with th args)